# It "must" was a challenging experience

Tags: modal-verbs

> It was a challenging experience, wasn't it?

I want to emphasis the above statement using ***Must***. What should I say?

Is it OK to say it like this?

> It **must was** a challenging experience, wasn't it?

It doesn't sound good!

I've found a lot of examples where the Present Perfect has been used. So the following sentence seems to be better:

> It **must have been** a challenging experience, wasn't it (/hasn't it)?

But, doesn't this change the meaning? Has "It was a challenging experience" the different meaning compared to "It has been a challenging experience"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**was** is simple past, and **must** is a modal. We don't use simple past with modals (will, can, should, must, may etc): instead, we use it with present perfect.

> I must have been wrong
>   He can't have been very busy
>   Next week, I will have lived here for five years.
>   He should have got here by now.

There is another alternative for **must** + simple past: you can also say **had** + to-infinitive.

> It **had** to be a challenging experience

Regarding the question clause at the end, it has to match the modal:

> It must have been a challenging experience, **mustn't** it?